# How to load caffemodel for gender and age detection correct?

Tags: python, caffe

I wanna use OpenCV to predict the gender and the age of an person. I try to load the caffemodel and a prototxt for the model but for some reason it won't load. What is the reason?

code:

```
import requests
import cv2
import numpy as np
import imutils


genderProto = "gender_deploy.prototxt"
genderModel = "gender_net.caffemodel"
ageNet = cv2.dnn.readNet(genderModel, genderProto)
```

error:

`error: OpenCV(4.5.3) /private/var/folders/24/8k48jl6d249_n_qfxwsl6xvm0000gn/T/pip-req-build-xxsyexfp/opencv/modules/dnn/src/caffe/caffe_io.cpp:1121: error: (-2:Unspecified error) FAILED: fs.is_open(). Can't open "gender_deploy.prototxt" in function 'ReadProtoFromTextFile'`

Answer (score 0):

You can load caffe models in OpenCv using `readNetFromCaffe`

```
genderProto = "gender_deploy.prototxt"
genderModel = "gender_net.caffemodel"
ageNet = cv2.dnn.readNetFromCaffe(genderProto, genderModel)
```

https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.15/d6/d0f/group__dnn.html

Comment: Thanks! But same error appears. Obviously loading caffe is not the problem. The gender_deploy.prototxt is not possible to load. But this normally also a OpenCV object or?

Comment: can you try with absolute path?